# react-redux asynchronous get method been called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

i'm working on my react blog project and i'm making a get request using an api using (redux-react) but my problem is that the function is been called continuously, instead it been called once
below is my code and image showing the continuous api call
pls can anyone help out
action file where i'm making d api call

```
export function fetchArticles(){
    return function(dispatch){
        const url  = `${baseUrl}/articles/list`
        return axios.get(url).then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data)
        dispatch( {type:articles.DISPLAY_ARTICLE, payload:res.data.data})
    })
    }
    
}
```

reducer file

```
function displayArticles (state=initialState, action){
    if(action.type===DISPLAY_ARTICLE){
        console.log(state)
        return Object.assign({}, state,{
            articles: state.articles.concat(action.payload)
        })
    }
    console.log(state)
    return state
}


function rootReducer(state=initialState, action){

    switch(action.type){
        case DISPLAY_ARTICLE:
            return displayArticles(state, action)
            break;
```

component file

```
function mapStateToProp (state){
    return {articles: state.articles}
}
const Index = (props)=>{
  useEffect(()=>{ 
    props.fetchArticles()

  }
  )

export default connect(
    (mapStateToProp),
    {fetchArticles}
)(Index)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because the way how you wrote your `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{ 
  props.fetchArticles()
  // you did not pass any dependency array
} )
```

Since you did not pass any dependency array, function inside `useEffect` will get called in every rerender. with `connect` you are subscribed to the store. every time subscription detects a state change your component will rerender, since you did not pass the dependency array, the function inside `useEffect` will run which will fetch the data over and over again.

```
useEffect(()=>{ 
  props.fetchArticles()
  // empty dependency array means run only when initial mounting
},[] )
```